# IDLE 3.7 can't scroll up

Tags: python, python-idle

IDLE 3.6.2 suddenly started crashing repeatedly today on my Mac (OSX 10.12.6), so I installed 3.7.0. I can't scroll up in 3.7; when I do a two-finger scroll on the trackpad either up or down, the IDLE window scrolls down. [This](https://bugs.python.org/issue34047) suggests that it was an issue that they fixed. So how come it's still a problem for me?

Update: I installed 3.6.6 over 3.6.2 and now I can't scroll up in 3.6 either. Please help!!

Comment: It's fixed in their issue tracking, but it's probably not in the 3.7 build you're running. Your link says it was closed on 2018-09-25 00:10 and the python.org OSX 3.7.0 build is from 2018-06-27. So I would say you don't have this fix.

Comment: But I just installed 3.7.0 today. You mean they haven't put the fix in the download that's available now?

Comment: A permanent fix to the problem is to stop using IDLE in favor of a less clunky IDE :)

Comment: I know. But why did it have to be *today*

Comment: You may have downloaded it today, but that doesn't mean the version on their website is the most recent possible version that's been built. And it's not, it's from June. The only way you can fix this is to compile cpython yourself. Unfortunately you might have to just use a different editor for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this and other problems is in the release candidate at https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-371rc1/.  The final 3.7.1 will be out in a week or so, but the above works now for me.  For 3.6, go to https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-367rc1/.