# How to launch atom from conda environment

Tags: python, anaconda, atom-editor

IDLE has been [buggy lately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52612563/idle-3-7-cant-scroll-up/52618401#52618401) and Spyder is [unbearably slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53381373/ipython-console-in-spyder-extremely-slow-in-anaconda) so I'm trying atom in Anaconda. I installed atom:

```
$ conda activate py37
$ conda install atom
Downloading and Extracting Packages
future-0.17.1        | 700 KB    | ######################################################### | 100% 
atom-0.4.1           | 110 KB    | ######################################################### | 100% 
$ conda list
# packages in environment at /anaconda3/envs/py37:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0  
astroid                   2.0.4                    py37_0  
atom                      0.4.1            py37h0a44026_0
```

but I can't launch it:

```
$ atom
-bash: atom: command not found
$ atom --new-instance
-bash: atom: command not found
```

I also tried installing like this:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda atom
Downloading and Extracting Packages
ca-certificates-2018 | 124 KB    | ################################################################################################################## | 100% 
openssl-1.1.1        | 4.6 MB    | ################################################################################################################## | 100% 
atom-0.4.1           | 110 KB    | ################################################################################################################## | 100% 
certifi-2018.10.15   | 138 KB    | ################################################################################################################## | 100% 
$ conda list
# packages in environment at /anaconda3/envs/py37:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py37_0  
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py37_0  
astroid                   2.0.4                    py37_0  
atom                      0.4.1            py37h0a44026_0    anaconda
```

and I get the same error.
How do I launch atom?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool** (such as which editor should I use), software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers (see https://www.xkcd.com/378/) and spam. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for more details.

Comment: @quant ok i removed that

Comment: When you do `conda install atom`, I think you are installing this https://pypi.org/project/atom/. If you want the text editor, see here https://flight-manual.atom.io/getting-started/sections/installing-atom/.

Answer (score 0):

The Atom application can be launched in a few ways. The easiest is to open the Applications folder and double click on the Atom icon.  To launch from the command line type 'open -a /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom'. Or go to /usr/local/bin and set the following link: atom@ -> /Applications/Atom.app/Contents/Resources/app/atom.sh

After this last link then just type Atom on the command line.
You could also make an alias:

alias atom=open -a /applications/Atom.app/Contents/MacOS/Atom